# Under what assumption on a proper map does the preimage of sufficiently small neighborhood is homotopy equivalent to the fiber?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gn.general-topology, homotopy-theory, stratifications, paracompactness

Let $\pi\colon X\rightarrow Y$ be a proper map of topological spaces. Let's assume that both $X$ and $Y$ are paracompact, Hausdorff and locally weakly contractible. Then is it enough to conclude that for any point $y\in Y$ there is a base of open neighborhoods $U\subset Y$ such that the preimage $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is weakly homotopy equivalent to $\pi^{-1}(y)$? And if not, what is the natural generality in which this would be true?

Comment: I suspect any space filling curve $[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1] \times [0,1]$ is a counterexample as stated.

Comment: If $\pi$ is definable in the sense of o-minimality, then we have a stratification theorem that breaks Y into locally closed subsets over which $\pi$ is isomorphic to a projection. For example, any analytic map between real vector spaces is definable in the analytic structure of the reals. Maybe in this case we also get the homotopy property you mention?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Ah, good point! and I guess the standard Peano curve is given by a proper map in particular..

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon actually yes, I was really hoping that at least for analytic maps between analytic subsets of R^n this should be true, though I still didn't have any concrete argument in mind. this stratification theorem seems nice; is it also possible to see how the preimages of these strata glue inside X? like e.g. would it be true that I have a continuous "specialization" map from the fiber over bigger stratum to a smaller one..?

Comment: @user42024 I'm not an expert in o-minimality, just a casual admirer. But I'm guessing that something very strong will be true--there will be Mather-style control data (as in a Whitney stratification) all of which is definable, and gives fully compatible definable homotopies on any sufficiently small neighborhood of a point. I also expect that this has already been worked out! Not quite sure what to google, though.